# Build .NETCORE 1.0 api application in the pipeline

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My application hosted in azure uses old .NETCORE 1.0 SDK. There wasn't any commits for more than a month and when I committed some changes today, it failed to build. I checked the pipeline and I found that it failed on Run dotnet with this error

> A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version
>   [1.0.0-preview2-003131] from [D:\a\1\s\global.json] was not found.

Does it mean azure devops does not support .NETCORE 1.0 anymore? Do I need to upgrade the application to use .NETCORE 2.x?

Any help will be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Even if you find out a way to let Azure devops works with .NETCORE 1.0, I suggest you to moving your application to .NETCORE 3.1. Previous versions are already obsolete.

Comment: thanks, may need to consider moving it then

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core .NET Core 1.x are long dead.

Comment: Hi ednu, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if you need any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several hosted agents, and the different agents have different software installed on it. The list of agents can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops

the window 2019 hosted agent has the following software installed:
https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md

the window 2016 hosted agent has the following software installed:
https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md

As you can see in the list, the windows 2016 hosted agent still has a .net Core 1.0 version installed. If updating you project to a new .net Core version is not an option, you might be able to build your project on this agent.

You can set the agent to build to windows 2016 by using the following yaml:

```
jobs:
- job: Build_Web
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually selected vs2017-win2016 hosted agent and got that error. After that error, the process actually tried to find the sdk, but based on the printed sdk, the oldest was 1.1.14

Comment: In that case, you have 2 options. Use a private agent with the sdk you need installed, or update your application to use a newer version of the sdk

Answer (score 0):

Agree with **PaulVrugt** that you should use `Windows 2016 hosted agent` to build your application if you do want to use `.net core 1`.

But you may also need an extra [Use .net core Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) in the first task of the pipeline to specify the version you want to use.

This task can be used to change the version of .NET Core used in subsequent tasks like `.NET Core cli task`. And this is necessary cause Azure Devops will automatically pick the latest version of `.net core sdk` unless you use this task to let the pipeline know which version of sdk do you want to use in following tasks.